# Obtener el return destro de un $.ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo la siguiente funcion que es para que me de un arreglo para otra funsión.

```
function getAnio(){
var urlAPI = sessionStorage.getItem("url");// la url la obtengo de la session que inicie
var getyear= $("#anio").val();//Es el año que quiero consultar desde un input en la pagina.
var datos= new Array;
var datos = (
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: urlAPI+"general/",
    data: {
      param: "grafica",
      anio: getyear
    }
  }).done(function(data) {//resepción de la informacion en formato ajax
    console.log(data);
    var dato= new Array;//inicializacion de un array para los datos que necesito.
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {//procesado de los datos para que me entregue el arreglo.
      dato.push(data[i].mes);
    }
    console.log(dato);//resultado que necesito =>[ "0","0","0","0","0","10","19","5","3","0","0","0" ]
    return dato;// y aqui no me retorna el arreglo. 
  })
);    
}
```

Haciendo pruebas, los datos si llegan al ajax pero al momento de querer recuperar los datos para usarlos en otra función usando un "return", no me retorna nada. Hay alguna forma de que pueda hacer el retorno?

Comment: Las llamadas a Ajax son asíncronas, por tanto, debes retornar el valor a una función. Poniendo algo así en la parte del `done`  debería funcionar: `processData(dato); return dato;` sabiendo que debe existir una `function processData (dato) {  //trabajar aquí con dato}` Dicho eso, no entiendo qué sentido tiene esto en tu código: `var datos = (
$.ajax({  ... `  ¿?

Comment: [Aquí hay un ejemplo funcional](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/133488/29967) donde los datos que trae la llamada Ajax son pasados a otra función. Aquí, por motivos de ese código, además de los datos, se pasa otro parámetro (`idSalida`), el cual no es necesario en tu caso. El ejemplo muestra el contexto completo, lo cual es importante también. Desde `function` se hace la llamada a Ajax una vez recuperados los elementos del DOM que interesan, y desde dentro de Ajax se llama a la función que procesará los datos

Comment: El uso que quiero hacer es para un plugin de gráfica, para mostrar el numero de servicios realizados cada mes en el año, por eso requiero esa funcion, para el parametro de "data" y muestre la gráfica.

Comment: Revisaste el ejemplo del enlace. Ahí está todo el contexto, si lo haces así debería funcionar.

Answer (score -1):

Para obtener la solución que deseas podrías usar la siguiente función:

```
//funcion ajax con método de parámetro
function ajax(ruta, metodo, datos) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: ruta,
    data: datos,
    beforeSend: function(res) {},
    success: function(res) {},
    complete: function(res) {},
    error: function(res) {}
  }).done(function(res) {
    metodo(res)
  })
}

//obtención de datos
function mapList(data){
 console.log(data)
}

//ejecutamos la función así:
ajax("URL", mapList, {})
```

Espero te pueda servir.